# Wordpress - ftp'd site/exported database to localhost, localhost images still point to .com, why?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, .htaccess, localhost

I FTP'd over the entire wordpress site and exported the Database and got it running on my localhost throught WAMP, but for some reason the links and folder are still pointing towards it's .com, and a 404 error comes up as well.

I suspect it has something to do with .htaccess but I'm not sure.. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) under **General > Settings**?

They might still point to old domain.

Answer (score 1):

Transferring the site over FTP to your local machine is the same as "moving" it to a new domain. Wordpress provides specific instructions for such a move which you can find @

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

`When Your Domain Name or URLs Change
When your domain name or URLs change - i.e. from http://example.com/blog to http://example.com, or http://example.com to http://newexample.com - there are additional concerns. The files and database can be moved, however references to the old domain name or location will remain in the database, and that can cause issues with links or theme display.`

`If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL marked. When this changes, things break. To avoid that serialization issue, you have two options:`

`Only perform a search and replace on the wp_posts table.
Use the Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script to safely change all instances. ( If you are a developer, use this option. It is a one step process as opposed to the 15-step procedure below )`